# Kentico: Recreating CMSDesk behaviour with User Contribution webpart

Tags: web-parts, kentico

When I upload a file (doctype CMS.File) using the Kentico CMSDesk, it automatically names the Document, based on what the file uploaded is called, with no need for a separate FileName input.

Can this be reproduced via the User Contribution web part? That is, can FileName (and or DocumentName) be automatically generated using from the name of the file uploaded in this web part?

Many thanks, Oli.

Answer (score 2):

For any document type you can set the source field for the document name. If you will check the CMS.File document type in Site Manager -> Development -> Document types and switch to Fields tab, you will see that the Document name source field is set to the file upload field. You can do the same for your document type used in user contributions.